# C strcmp fails to compare with space

Tags: c, strcmp

I try to see if formula[i] is a space and if it is number should be zero. But apparently it fails to compare them :S I'm new to C, so does somebody know the problem?

Note: this is not my whole code but only the essential part to understand the problem.

```
char formula[50] = "1 4 + 74 /";
int number = 0;

for (int i = 0; i != strlen(formula); i++)
{
    if(!isdigit(formula[i]))
    {
      if (strcmp(&formula[i], " ") == 0)
      {
         number = 0; 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: strcmp compares STRINGS, not CHARACTERS. You're comparing the entire back end of your formula to a string containing a single space. Of course they don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because the string `" 4 + 74 /"` is not equal to the string `" "`.

I think what you actually want to compare here are characters, which is as simple as

```
if (formula[i] == ' ')
{
    // ...
}
```

For completeness sake, there is a way to perform a string comparison on a prefix of two strings, with the function `strncmp`, where you can specify how many characters of a string to match.

```
if (strncmp(&formula[i], " ", 1))
{
    // ...
}
```

which would be equivalent to the caracter comparison above.

Comment: Thanks :) I actually tried that at the first place but then I compared with " " instead of ' ' which didn't work :p. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

That is because they're not equal.

When you do `&formula[i]`, you get a pointer to the character at location `i`. The string, viewed from that location, continues until the terminating `'\0'`-character, i.e. that's *not* a 1-character string.

Just do a direct comparison:

```
if(formula[i] == ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) compares two strings(two `const char*`s ending with a `\0`) and not two characters. In your case,use

```
if(formula[i]==' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

*The &formula[i] gives you a pointer to where i is allocated.*

To tackle the problem , you have to do the following:

```
if (formula[i] == ' ')
```